# macOS Privileged Helper doesn't have access to a filesystem path?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, launchd

Halp! I am writing an internal macOS app for our IT staff to perform some org-specific tasks, and am also adding some shortcuts for simple, but common tasks that they do. One of those tasks is to rename a user when migrating between domains. This app has a Privileged Helper available (via `SMjobBless`) to perform most of the tasks. However, it appears that this helper tool, despite its privileged execution context, is unable to rename a user's home directory.

My first attempt at implementing this specific task in the helper was to run a short shell script via `Process()` (a technique used successfully for dozens of other tasks in this helper).

```swift
let script = """
            set -e
            mv '\(homeDirPath)' /Users/\(toUsername)
            dscl . -change /Users/\(fromUsername) NFSHomeDirectory '\(homeDirPath)' '/Users/\(toUsername)'
            dscl . -change /Users/\(fromUsername) RecordName \(fromUsername) \(toUsername)
            """
```

I get the following output on stderr (`/Users/newname` verified to not exist):

`mv: rename /Users/oldname to /Users/newname: Operation not permitted`

> Trying this as a non-root user gives a different error: `mv: rename /Users/oldname to /Users/newname: Permission denied`

Okay, weird. Add `whoami` to the top of the script to double check the user context: `root`. Well... interesting. Wth, I can do this just fine via `sudo` in my user session.

Then I try using FileManager thinking there might be some SIP interference or sandboxing for child processes of a launchdaemon (despite not finding any docs that say this), but I still get an error - but more verbose this time:

`Error: “oldname” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “Users”`.

I've tried searching for documentation for whatever restriction I am up against, but I'm at a loss. The directory doesn't appear to be under SIP's protection, and I can't find any docs for daemon sandboxing outside of the app store (the parent app does *not* have the App Sandbox capability enabled). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

*Update:* It doesn't appear to be affected by 10.14's Privacy Protection. Adding the helper to "Full Disk Access" doesn't resolve. Perhaps I am adding the helper incorrectly: had to change the build target to 10.14 (which will be a problem), then dragged the helper binary from within the App bundle into the list. I cannot add it from `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/` - it is greyed out as an option to add.

*Update 2:* Correction, it does appear to be FDA related. iTerm was in the FDA list. Removing it causes it to throw `Operation not permitted`, then adding it back resolves. So I'm now chasing down how to properly add the helper to the FDA list.

Comment: I believe the `mv` command will refuse to delete the destination item without warning. Use the `-f` option to override this. I suspect that `mv` wants to prompt the user for a `y` or `n` answer on the replacement, but since you're not running an interactive shell it can't. When you run these commands as a regular user `mv` smacks into your lack of permission to change `/Users` before it gets to the point of replacing the target. To debug this, write your commands to an executable script file (I'm a big fan of `#!/bin/bash -vx` for debugging) and run the script via `sudo` until it works.

Comment: For this task, I actually would like `mv` to fail in case the destination exists, which is why I left it off. However, I did try adding the `-f` force flag to see if it made a difference (it did not), but I am also sure the destination directory I am testing with does not already exist.

Comment: Well, it was just a guess—and worth every penny you paid for it. ;) But using `sudo` to test your script as root might prove helpful in isolating the problem. You definitely cannot rename something in `/Users` as a regular user, so nothing you attempt as a regular user will get you any closer to a solution. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it's confirmed - Mojave's Privacy Protections apply even to privileged tools. The solution was to make the helper binary executable by all so it can be allowed to be added to the Full Disk Access table.

Hopefully, this helps someone in the future who is initially puzzled by what they're seeing.

Here's to hoping that Apple adds a standardized, easier method for the user to grant this access to helpers.

Comment: Actually, as I've discovered in my own app, Mojave's sandbox rules are applied on a per-user basis. User 'james' can grant an executable "Full Disk Access", but that only applies when that executable is running as 'james'. If the executable is launched by 'amber' it doesn't get Full Disk Access, and this applies equally to 'root'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just, grr.